# How to display value of one textarea to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Displaying value of text field works fine, but how to do the same with textarea?

Working:

```
print "<tr><td>Date: <input type=\"text\" size =\"30\" value=\"".$row["date"]."\" name=\"date\">";
```

Does not work:

```
print "<textarea input type= \"text\" style=\"width:300px; height:200px;\"  name =\"date\" value=\"".$rinda["date"]."\" wrap=physical></textarea>";
```

Comment: This should help: `print "<textarea>".$rinda["date"]."</textarea>";`.

Comment: A textarea doesn't have an value attribute.

Comment: Use google before asking here.

Comment: check answer. btw, bad idea to post one question in title and imply another in the post body.

Answer (score 0):

not a self contained element, and doesn't have an `input` attribute.

```
print "<textarea>".$rinda["date"]."</textarea>";
```

but it should.

but to answer the question,

[image: text swap]

jquery js

```
$(function() {
  var $text1 = $('#text1'),
      $text2 = $('#text2');

  $('#moveText').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $text2.val($text1.val());
      $text1.val('');
  })
})
```

html

```
<textarea name="text1" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<textarea name="text2" id="text2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="moveText">Move Text</button>
```

Comment: @emmanuel it shows the previous input, but i need to give further this information for update. How can i do that?